# Custom Eagle CAD part for Arduino Pro Mino

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to create a custom part for Arduino Pro Mini in Eagle 7.6.0 Light. The Arduino Pro Mini has pins A4 and A5 not on the edges but in the middle of the board (see image below).

I am trying to figure out what would be the best approach to create the custom part for these pins? I have put them in the center of the symbol when creating the custom part, but when I am in the Schematic view I only see the name of the pin (i.e. A4 or A5) but not sure where to connect (i.e. cant see red pin output).

**Schematic View**

[image]

**Part Symbol View**

[image]

**Arduino Pro Mini (A4 and A5 at top center)**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You are designing the *symbol*, not the package.  The symbol is what will be inserted into the schematic.  As the name implies, it is a symbolic representation of the part.  The physical layout of pins should have nothing to do with how a device is represented in a schematic.  That only matter in the package, since that defines the mechanical layout on the board.

No, don't ever put pins in the middle of a symbol like that.  A schematic must be clear and easily allow others to understand the circuit it is trying to communicate.  Making a mess as you are proposing goes against that purpose.

Forget physical pinout and pin order when making the schematic symbol.  Place pins by function.  Try to put power connections at top, grounds at bottom, input-only pins at left, pins of a sub-function together, etc.

Above all, don't make a mess.